# Why error.com redirect me to my wamp server localhost?

Tags: php, web, server, localhost, host

How this error.com works? When I enter error.com without https protocol it just redirects to my wamp server localhost.

But why? What is this error.com? [image]

Comment: Have you set it up in your `hosts` file? Or any browser addon that might do this? I get `Unable to connect` when accessing error.com

Comment: I don't set anything yet and also I don't think so that wamp server doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`127.0.0.1` is an local ip , its unique on all devices, whene you install any `http server` like `WIMP` or `apache2` , you activate automaticaly the http protocol on your local Ip's (ex:192.168.1.200)  and on your `loopback` ip (`127.0.0.1`)
in case of `error.com` :

it's has a DNS record that goes directly to the loopback address  `127.0.0.1`
When your device invokes a DNS server, convert the error.com domain name to IP, the DNS server replies with an address of `127.0.0.1`.
after , your device send request to ip geted by `dns` Request (127.0.0.1)

Comment: you can do all dns change you want , on your local device or local network
if you want to redirect facebook.com on you device to your localhost ,you can add an dns requrd in your hosts file like this : 127.0.0.1 facebook.com.
in thes mode , evertime you write facebook.com in your brwoser, You will see your local host.

Comment: hosts file on windows is in this location : `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

on linux :` /etc/hosts`